# How to access a windows forms comboboxes' variables? C#

Tags: c#, string, winforms, combobox, instance-variables

I have a small problem regarding C# and WindowsForms.
I'm trying to get `string SelectedItemName = combobox2.SelectedItem.ToString();` this variable in another class. For example I have this in my Form1.cs Class.

```
public void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileIniDataParser fileParser = new FileIniDataParser();
    IniData data = fileParser.ReadFile("config.ini");
    IniProgram classReference = new IniProgram();

    string SelectedItemName = (string)comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    // string _SelectedItemName = (string)comboBox2.SelectedText;

    Console.WriteLine(SelectedItemName);
    if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        testvariabel2.GetSessionName();
    }
}
```

And than my other Class CTestRack.cs looks like this:

```
if (_form1Object.comboBox2.SelectedIndex.ToString() != null)
{
    string SelectedItemName = _form1Object.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if (newDictionary.ContainsKey(SelectedItemName))
```

Now I've tried getting and setting the variable in the Form1 class but I was just getting Loop errors, now with this method I'm getting a NULLReferenceException.
By the way I was already looking into several related posts here in SO but didn't found my answer yet.
My question is just how do I get the active Text from the Combobox in my other Class as a String?

Comment: Where do you initialize `_form1Object`?

Comment: I Initialize it in the same function as the if statement is as following: `Form1 _form1Object = new Form1();`

Comment: `new Form1()`?.. You aren't accessing the same form, there should be plenty of duplicate questions around of how to access form1 from form2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure that `_form1Object`, is indeed set to the instance of form you want to access... It's hard to tell from above code if correct initialization of `_form1Object` is the problem here.
2. Assuming `_form1Object`, is correctly initialized, one bug in above code is that `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` property is an int.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx

It doesn't matter if there is SelectedItem or not, `comboBox2.SelectedIndex.ToString() != null` will always be true, but `comboBox2.SelectedItem` could still be null, and hence `comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()` would fail with NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that `comboBox2` doesn't have `SelectedItem`, you can check it
either by

```
comboBox2.SelectedItem != null
```

Or by

```
comboBox2.SelectedIndex >= 0
```

Something like that

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedItem != null) {
  string SelectedItemName = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

  Console.WriteLine(SelectedItemName);
  testvariabel2.GetSessionName();
}
else {
  // No selected item in the ComboBox
}

...

if (_form1Object != null)
  if (_form1Object.comboBox2.SelectedIndex >= 0) {
    string SelectedItemName = _form1Object.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    if (newDictionary.ContainsKey(SelectedItemName))
      ...
   }
```